# how can i retrieve the all details from array list

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have a one doubt in Servlets. in case if you know the solution about that please share with me. 
so now my problem is that...... i am developing one social networking application(practice purpose).when user clicks find followers button request goes to the servlet, in that servlet i have written jdbc code. database is giving all users details like name, email id, address, phone number, profile picture. so i have stored all details in array list. so i want to  retrieve the all details from the array list including image also . and i want to display all details on jsp page (front end page)..so how can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can override doGet method. Use foreach loop for iteration of arraylist. And keep image url inside arraylist not any java image class.